# How to put a limit of the clicks on the button in real time?

Tags: node.js, real-time, comet

I have a question recently: How can we realize the restriction on the button clicks in real time?
For example, there is a restriction in 10 clicks on a button. For example Bob clicked on the button and then Bob and Rob saw that there stayed 9 clicks. After the 10th pressing the button is disabled.

What will you advise?

Comment: Do you want to limit the click for all users, if two different users clicked on the button the number of clicks available is 8? If so, you need to use a comunication between all users of you site, then if Rob click you have to notify bob how many click remain. Maybe websocket will help you.

Comment: You'll need to use something to coordinate and mediate the clicks across browsers. Many developers might use socket.io for the "real-time" part, but ultimately, without a central service to decide whether a "click" is allowed based on the rules you've established, it's not practical (as you'll have race conditions).

Answer (score 0):

- Use a database to track the number of clicks

  - Depending on your functional needs, you probably want to be on the "immediate consistency" end of the spectrum vs "eventual consistency" so either use a traditional relational database with constraints and transactions or store the clicks in a single mongodb document you can update atomically.
- MongoDB You might set up a ClickTrackers collection and a document like:

.

```
{
  button: "reserveSeat":
  clickedBy: [userId1, userId2]
}
```

- Then you could use `$addToSet`
- a redis set might work well (assuming you are allowing 1 click per user)
- You will want some real-time libraries to help you push updates out to connected browsers. Perhaps meteor.js or socket.io.js
- There's no way to avoid the edge case of lag between showing a user there's 1 click left, someone else clicking it, and then the first user clicking it before the click count decreases to 0 (like buying tickets to a popular concert, for example), so you must handle this and write tests for it and have a UI to say to the user "oops no clicks left, actually, sorry"

Hopefully that gets you started, but as it is your question isn't following the stackoverflow guidelines as it is "too broad" and you haven't posted any code you've tried, so go try something and come back with some code snippets.